# How can I avoid semi-repeating groups of methods in java?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, dry

Let's say I have written the following methods:

```
public void submitForm1() {
        open();
        setField(1, "blah");
        setField(3, "bla");
        setField(4, "blah blah");
        submit();
    }

public void submitForm2() {
        open();
        setField(1, "blah");
        checkBox(1 , true);
        submit();
}

....

public void submitForm100() {
        open();
        setField(1, "bla");
        setField(2, "bla bla");
        setField(3, "blah");
        setArea(1, "blah blah");
        submit();
}
```

These methods make me feel I'm constantly repeating myself. I feel like it should be written something like this:

```
public void submitForm1() {
        MyMethods.submitForm(
            {SET_FIELD, 1, "blah"},
            {SET_FIELD, 3, "bla"},
            {SET_FIELD, 4, "blah blah"}
        );
    }

public void submitForm2() {
        MyMethods.submitForm(
            {SET_FIELD, 1, "blah"},
            {CHECKBOX, 1, true}
        );
}

....

public void submitForm100() {
        MyMethods.submitForm(
            {SET_FIELD, 1, "bla"},
            {SET_FIELD, 2, "bla bla"},
            {SET_FIELD, 3, "blah"},
            {SET_AREA, 1, "blah blah"},
        );
}
```

This way I won't have to repeat all of those open and submit methods over and over again.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
public interface FormSubmission {
  void set();
  default submitForm() {
    open();
    set();
    submit();
  }
}
```

Then you code would look like:

```
Map<Integer, FormSubmission > forms = new HashMap<> ();

//in constructor or static initialisation block:
forms.put(1, () -> { setField(1, "blah");
                     setField(3, "bla");
                     setField(4, "blah blah"); });
//etc.

public void submitForm(Integer i) {
  forms.get(i).submitForm(); //probably want to handle NPE here
}
```

It is similar to the command pattern.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *"callback"* for example. For that do something like this:

```
void doInSubmit(SubmitCallback callback)
{
    open();
    callback.call();
    submit();
}
```

And outside:

```
public void submitForm100() 
{
    doInSubmit(new SubmitCallback() 
    {
        void call()
        {
            setField(1, "bla");
            setField(2, "bla bla");
            setField(3, "blah");
            setArea(1, "blah blah");
        }
    })        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, but why don't you make this way:

```
public void submit() {
  open();
  switch(formNumber) {
    case 1:
    submitForm1();

    case 2:
    submitForm2();

    case 100:
    submitForm100();

    default:
    break;
  }
  submit();
}
```

Comment: Because they're different forms.